# Get (inner edge) contour pixel with opencv

Tags: opencv, image-processing, contour, edge-detection

I'm searching for a way to extract the "inner" contours of a binary image with opencv. I know that `findContours` extracts contours but I need the silhouette pixel which belong to the thresholded object in my binary image and not the outer contours.

Here is a fictive image which describes better what I'm searching for. I am searching for a method to extract the red contour.

[image: findcontours]

I already tried a naive approach in copying the original binary image and shrinking the copy by 2 pixels each side and filling up the edges with black pixels and used `findContours`but the outcome is not satisfying.

Answer (score 1):

You could just run `findContours()` on the negative image.

Answer (score -1):

Little update:

I solved it with opencv erosion and dilatation.